# How to compose multiple type-erased modules in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure, associated-types

Swift is amazing but not mature yet, so there are some compiler restrictions and among them is generic protocols. Generic protocols can't be used as a regular type annotation due to type-safety considerations. I found a workaround in a post by Hector Matos. [Generic Protocols & Their Shortcomings](https://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings)

The main idea is use type erasure to convert a generic protocol into a generic class, and it's cool. But I was stuck when applying this tech to more complex scenarios.

Assume there is an abstract Source, which produces data, and an abstract Procedure, which processes that data, and a pipeline, which combines a source and a procedure whose data types are matched.

```
protocol Source {
    associatedtype DataType
    func newData() -> DataType
}
protocol Procedure {
    associatedtype DataType
    func process(data: DataType)
}
protocol Pipeline {
    func exec() // The execution may differ
}
```

And the I want the client code to be simple as:

```
class Client {
    private let pipeline: Pipeline
    init(pipeline: Pipeline) {
        self.pipeline = pipeline
    }
    func work() {
        pipeline.exec()
    }
}

// Assume there are two implementation of Source and Procedure,
// SourceImpl and ProcedureImpl, whose DataType are identical.
// And also an implementation of Pipeline -- PipelineImpl

Client(pipeline: PipelineImpl(source: SourceImpl(), procedure: ProcedureImpl())).work()
```

Implementing Source and Procedure is simple, since they are at the bottom of the dependecy:

```
class SourceImpl: Source {
    func newData() -> Int { return 1 }
}

class ProcedureImpl: Procedure {
    func process(data: Int) { print(data) }
}
```

The PITA appears when implementing Pipeline

```
// A concrete Pipeline need to store the Source and Procedure, and they're generic protocols, so a type erasure is needed
class AnySource<T>: Source {
    private let _newData: () -> T
    required init<S: Source>(_ source: S) where S.DataType == T {
        _newData = source.newData
    } 
    func newData() -> T { return _newData() }
}
class AnyProcedure<T>: Procedure {
    // Similar to above.
}

class PipelineImpl<T>: Pipeline {
    private let source: AnySource<T>
    private let procedure: AnySource<T>
    required init<S: Source, P: Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) where S.DataType == T, P.DataType == T {
         self.source = AnySource(source)
         self.procedure = AnyProcedure(procedure)
    }
    func exec() {
         procedure.process(data: source.newData())
    }
}
```

Ugh, Actually this one works!
Am I kidding you? No.

I am not satisfied with this one, because the `initializer` of `PipelineImpl` is quite generic, so I want it to be in the protocol (Am I wrong with this obsession?). And this leads to two end:

1. The protocol `Pipeline` will be generic. The `initializer` contains a where clause which refers to `placeholder T`, so I need to move the `placeholder T` into protocol as an `associated type`. Then the protocol turns into a generic one, which means I can't use it directly in my client code -- may need another type erasure.

   Although I can bear the troublesome of writing another type erasure for the `Pipeline` protocol, I don't know how to deal with the `initializer function` because the `AnyPipeline<T>` class must implement the initializer regarding to the protocol but it's only a [thunk class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) actually, which shouldn't implement any initializer itself.
2. Keep the protocol `Pipeline` non-generic. With writing the `initializer` like

   ```
   init<S: Source, P: Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) 
   where S.DataType == P.DataType
   ```

   I can prevent the protocol being generic. This means the protocol only states that "Source and Procedure must have same DataType and I don't care what it is". This makes more sense but I failed to implement a concrete class confirming this protocol

   ```
   class PipelineImpl<T>: Protocol {
       private let source: AnySource<T>
       private let procedure: AnyProcedure<T>
       init<S: Source, P: Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) 
       where S.DataType == P.DataType {
           self.source = AnySource(source) // doesn't compile, because S is nothing to do with T
           self.procedure = AnyProcedure(procedure) // doesn't compile as well
       }
       // If I add S.DataType == T, P.DataType == T condition to where clasue, 
       // the initializer won't confirm to the protocol and the compiler will complain as well
   }
   ```

So, how could I deal with this?

Thanks for reading `allll` this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating this somewhat (unless I'm missing something) – your `PipelineImpl` doesn't appear to be anything more than a wrapper for a function that takes data from a `Source` and passes it to a `Procedure`.

As such, it doesn't need to be generic, as the outside world doesn't need to know about the type of data being passed – it just needs to know that it can call `exec()`. As a consequence, this also means that (for now at least) you don't need the `AnySource` or `AnyProcedure` type erasures.

A simple implementation of this wrapper would be:

```
struct PipelineImpl : Pipeline {

    private let _exec : () -> Void

    init<S : Source, P : Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) where S.DataType == P.DataType {
        _exec = { procedure.process(data: source.newData()) }
    }

    func exec() {
        // do pre-work here (if any)
        _exec()
        // do post-work here (if any)
    }
}
```

This leaves you free to add the initialiser to your `Pipeline` protocol, as it need not concern itself with what the actual `DataType` is – only that the source and procedure must have the same `DataType`:

```
protocol Pipeline {
    init<S : Source, P : Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) where S.DataType == P.DataType
    func exec() // The execution may differ
}
```

Comment: Good point, but there may exist some different pre&post work to do in different `exec` functions. However, @Hamish's approach still works in that case, I think. Thanks!

Comment: @NandiinBao Ah, I see – I have edited my answer to account for this. Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

@Hamish pointed out a good solution.

After posted this question, I did some tests and also found out a workaround

```
class PipelineImpl<T>: Pipeline {
    required init<S: Source, P: Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) where S.DataType == T, P.DataType == T {
        // This initializer does the real jobs.
        self.source = AnySource(source)
        self.procedure = AnyProcedure(procedure)
    }
    required convenience init<S: Source, P: Procedure>(source: S, procedure: P) where S.DataType == P.DataType {
        // This initializer confirms to the protocol and forwards the work to the initializer above
        self.init(source: source, procedure: procedure)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second initialiser will actually call itself recursively, as the compiler cannot guarantee that `DataType == T` – therefore `self.init` can only refer to itself.

Comment: I tested it in Xcode playground, and a call to init(source: procedure:) will actually invoke the first initializer and the second one never called. The second one is there only for confirming to the protocol. However, by doing this, I might have lost the point of including the initializer signature in protocol...

Comment: Furthermore, you're right. If I make the first initializer private, and call something like `PipelineImpl<Int>(source: source, procedure: procedure)`, it would fall into a dead loop. I didn't realize it.

Comment: You can invoke the second initialiser by passing in a source and procedure where the `DataType`s match, but they don't match `T` (for example a `SourceImpl` and `ProcedureImpl` instance where the `DataType` is `Int` into a `PipelineImpl<String>` initialiser). Also, as you mention, this will also cause problems by having the second initialiser as a protocol requirement – as for a function with a `<T : Pipeline>` generic placeholder, calling `T(source:procedure:)` will always recurse for when `T` is a `PipelineImpl`.